# pgfplot axis title position

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to obtain the result that appear on the right (compiling the following MWE) by using `title style`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
       \usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,patterns,shapes.arrows}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tikzscale}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
       \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
       \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,colormaps}pictures

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[title=(a),
                   title style={at={(0,1)},
                   anchor=north west,
                   draw=black,fill=white}]
        \addplot[blue] {x};
     \end{axis}
     \begin{axis}[xshift=10cm]
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {$(a)$};
        \addplot[red] {x};
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A related (if not the same!) answered question is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240823/position-of-groupplot-titles-in-tikz) and suggests to use `title style={at={(0.1,0.8)}}`. I'd like to use, instead, something like `title style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west}`, but as you can see, the result is not exactly what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `title style` does `every axis title/.append style`, while in the default title style there is `yshift=6pt`. Use `every axis title/.style={..}` instead of `title style={..}`, that will redefine the style completely.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

   \begin{axis}[title=(a),every axis title/.style={below right,at={(0,1)},draw=black,fill=white}]
   \addplot[blue] {x};
   \end{axis}
   \begin{axis}[xshift=10cm]
   \node[draw=black,fill=white,anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {(a)};
   \addplot[red] {x};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```